# Inserting into dynamic column name using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do you insert values into a dynamic column name in SQLAlchemy? I am trying to insert values into a table using dynamic column names that are passed into the function.

I have tried:

```py
        field_id = "column_name"

        query = (
            insert(
                TableName
            )
            .values(
                getattr(TableName.c, field_id)=value
            )
        )
```

But that tells me I can't assign a value to an expression

```
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant \"==\"?"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a dictionary, and then unpack it, like this:

```py
insert(tablename).values(**{field_id: 'foo'})
```

Comment: Great thank-you, that worked a charm, I was being a bit dumb.